# Electric dipole moment and magnetic moment

Tags: electromagnetism, hamiltonian

What is the intuitive explanation for electric and magnetic moments? How would we justify their presence in the Hamiltonians, for example, $$H=-\overline\mu.\overline{B}$$and,
$$H=-\overline{d}.\overline{E}$$
I am not understanding the physical realization of these quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets deal with electric dipoles, magnetic ones are similar.

We have a particle at position $\mathbf{\bar{r}}$ and want to consider how it could interact with electromagnetic potentials. Lets start with the scalar potential $\mathbf{\phi}$. You could say that Hamiltonian ($H$) of the particle will have the following form:

$$
H=H\left(\phi\left(\mathbf{\bar{r}}\right)\right)
$$

And this is a good start, but a more general *possible* dependency is:

$$
H=H\left(\phi\left(\mathbf{\bar{r}}\right),\:\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi\left(\mathbf{\bar{r}}\right)\right)
$$

Lets expand it for small values of potential:

$$
H\approx H_0+\phi\left(\mathbf{\bar{r}}\right)\partial_\phi H_0 +\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi\left(\mathbf{\bar{r}}\right).\partial_{\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi}H_0
$$

What we can then do is estimate the effects we would expect to see if the following constants were non-zero:

$$
\partial_\phi H_0,\,\partial_{\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi}H_0
$$

If we were to detect the effects, we could derive the values for the constants above. The former will be proportional to the electric charge of the particle, whilst the latter to the electric dipole of the particle. However it is important to remember that the names and definitions of these terms (charge & dipole) are conventions, and the only reason we talk about electric dipoles is that they can often be observed in atomic excitations (and many other places).

**So my logic is this: those terms *could* be in Hamiltonian, and we do *measure* effects consistent with their presence. This justifies their presence in the Hamiltonian.**

What do you mean by the physical realization of electric dipole? One example would be two charges of equal but opposite magnitude in close proximity. But this is just one possible example. Another example, from the world of RF, is a small dipole antenna. Another example, a water molecule etc. etc. It is a little easier to define the mathematical form of electric dipole in terms of charge density, but I don't think that this is what you are after.